# Unknown function: 'getFontColor'

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to use getFontColor() in a conditional concatenate formula, but google sheets keeps throwing the error Unknown function: 'getFontColor'. How can this be? The function is in google's documentation.

here is the full formula:

```
=IF(getFontColor('DRAFT Compliance Spreadsheet'!B2)="#cc0000", CONCATENATE('DRAFT Compliance Spreadsheet'!B$1, ", "))
```

Comment: share the script you use

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit of a noob-- doesn't getFontColor come default?

Comment: nope, getFontColor is not internal function. you will need to add script to your spreadsheet and only then you can use the formula from your question

Comment: I tried running the script at this link: [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/boolean-condition#getFontColor())
but the script editor threw an unexpected { error

Comment: would [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getfontcolor/) work? I'm not sure what to put in range, idk why it says "B2:D4"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Paste this in your script editor and save:

```
function getFontColor(cell) {
  var rangeName = cell.split("!");
  var sheet = rangeName[0].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
  var range = rangeName[1].replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheet);
  var fontColor = sheet.getRange(range).getFontColor();
  return fontColor;
}
```

Then replace your formula with this:

```
=IF(getFontColor(CELL("address", 'DRAFT Compliance Spreadsheet'!B2))="#cc0000", CONCATENATE('DRAFT Compliance Spreadsheet'!B$1, ", "))
```

### Example:

**Using getFontColor custom function:**

[image]

---

**Using your formula:**

[image]

Draft Compliance Spreadsheet sample data:

[image]

### References:

- [Custom Function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Class Range](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range)
- [Class Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)
- [Class Spreadsheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Is there a way to do this so I could drag it across and have the inputs change? I tried using CELL("address",B2) instead of "B2", but that gave an error